# What test should be used for one ordinal predictor and two continuous responses?

Tags: ordinal-data

I have a longitudinal data set divided into 9 samples. The same individuals are measured repeatedly, but not all are present in all 9 samples (mortality). I want to predict two continuous variables given the measurement 1st through 9th. My goal is to be able to say something like: "over the sampling period, Y1 and Y2 increased/decreased/stayed the same", rather than looking at pairwise comparisons.

Jonckheere-Terpstra wants independent samples, but Friedman wants balanced numbers in each sample. What test would be appropriate given the data?

Comment: The Friedman test lacks power.  If OK to analyze one continuous response at a time, consider [generalized least squares](https://hbiostat.org/rmsc/long.html) with a continuous time correlation pattern such as AR1 to make maximum use of all available longitudinal measurements.  The analysis would use actual measurements.  **But** if you want to consider mortality as a bad outcome (usually a good idea) look at [longitudinal ordinal models](https://hbiostat.org/rmsc/markov.html).